# How to control the execution of tasks that depends on the download of a file

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that runs every two minutes. The first task tries to download a file and the subsequents tasks manipulate this downloaded file.

I'm using a control file that sets a True value when the download is done successfully and then my other scripts check first if the download is set to True in this control file.

I was just wondering if there is a better way to execute my other scripts instead of running them all in every two minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Could you give more precisions your problem?

If I understood your problem here some indications:

1. Instead of using a control file use xcom to pass parameters between tasks. This isn't a solution to your problem but don't use files to pass the parameters since you could end up with concurrency issues.
2. To verify the download you could use a [file sensor](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/file_sensor.html) instead. And then define the dependencies as follow : `download_task >> file_sensor >> script_to_exec_task`. Don't forget to correctly configure the timeout on the sensor depending on your constraints and needs.